# Properly configured file won't 'make'

Tags: make

I'm trying to install module_init_tools offline. I downloaded the installation file, stuck it on a USB and moved it over to my Linux computer. I extracted all the files and ran the configure command. Unfortunately, 'make' always fails, giving me the Error 1 message.

[image: Terminal results]

Comment: Please do not use images where text will do.

Comment: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Answer (score 1):

You're barking up the wrong tree, `module-init-tools` is obsolete. It's been replaced by [`kmod`](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/kmod) which should already be installed on your system.